# Excel Online: get date range of start date column and end date column

Tags: excel-online

I am trying to get the list of all dates between the start date and end date from an item newly added to the table and put it in a column in another sheet.

I am new to Excel Online and I'm not sure how to apply this.

Here is a sample:

| name | startdt | enddt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ann | 01/01/2024 | 01/04/2024 |
| ben | 01/03/2024 | 01/05/2024 |

say ben's details is the newly added item, so in another sheet the list of all dates will now look like this:

| column A | column B |
| --- | --- |
| 01/01/2024 | ann |
| 01/02/2024 | ann |
| 01/03/2024 | ann |
| 01/04/2024 | ann |
| 01/03/2024 | ben |
| 01/04/2024 | ben |
| 01/05/2024 | ben |

your help is greatly appreciated, thank you.